# Why do virtual memory addresses for linux binaries start at 0x8048000?

Tags: linux, x86, elf, memory-layout

Disassembling an ELF binary on a Ubuntu x86 system I couldn't help but notice that the code(.text) section starts from the virtual address 0x8048000 and all lower memory addresses seem to be unused.

This seems to be rather wasteful and all Google turns up is either [folklore involving STACK_TOP](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.development.system/2006-02/msg00090.html) or protection against null-pointer dereferences. The latter case looks like it can be fixed by using a single page instead of leaving a 128MB gap.

So my question is this - is there a definitive answer to why the layout has been fixed to these values or is it just an arbitrary choice?

Comment: I don't know the actual answer; but perhaps this article might either help or at least provide an interesting read! http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the ELF execution entry point virtual address of the form 0x80xxxxx and not zero 0x0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187484/why-is-the-elf-execution-entry-point-virtual-address-of-the-form-0x80xxxxx-and-n)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [Linkers and loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker04.html) book:

> On 386 systems, the text base address is 0x08048000, which permits a reasonably large stack below the text while still staying above address 0x08000000, permitting most programs to use a single second-level page table. (Recall that on the 386, each second-level table maps 0x00400000 addresses.)