# How to correctly use a simple linker script? Executable gets SIGKILL when run

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-scripts

I'm trying to understand deeper linking process and linker scripts...looking at binutils doc i found a simple linker script implementation that i've improved by adding some commands:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386", "elf32-i386",
          "elf32-i386")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)

ENTRY(mymain)

SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x10000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   . = 0x8000000;
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

My program is a very simple program:

```
void mymain(void)
{
  int a;
  a++;
}
```

Now i tried to build an executable:

```
gcc -c main.c
ld -o prog -T my_script.lds main.o
```

But if i try to run `prog` it receives a `SIGKILL` during startup. I know that when a program is compiled and linked with the command:

```
gcc prog.c -o prog
```

the final executable is the product also of other object files like `crt1.o`, `crti.o` and `crtn.o` but what about my case? Which is the correct way to use this linker scripts?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suspect that your code is running just fine, and getting into trouble at the end: what do you expect to happen *after* the `a++`?

`mymain()` is just an ordinary C function, which will try to return to its caller.

But you've set it as the ELF entry point, which tells the ELF loader to jump to it once it has loaded the program segments in the right place - and it doesn't expect you to return.

Those "other object files like `crt1.o`, `crti.o` and `crtn.o`" normally handle this stuff for C programs.  The ELF entry point for a C program isn't `main()` - instead, it's a wrapper which sets up an appropriate environment for `main()` (e.g. setting up the `argc` and `argv` arguments on the stack or in registers, depending on platform), calls `main()` (with the expectation that it may return), and then invokes the `exit` system call (with the return code from `main()`).

---

*[Update following comments:]*

When I try your example with `gdb`, I see that it does indeed fail on returning from `mymain()`: after setting a breakpoint on `mymain`, and then stepping through instructions, I see that it performs the increment, then gets into trouble in the function epilogue:

```
$ gcc -g -c main.c
$ ld -o prog -T my_script.lds main.o
$ gdb ./prog
...
(gdb) b mymain
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10006: file main.c, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/prog 

Breakpoint 1, mymain () at main.c:4
4         a++;
(gdb) display/i $pc
1: x/i $pc
0x10006 <mymain+6>:     addl   $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
(gdb) si
5       }
1: x/i $pc
0x1000a <mymain+10>:    leave  
(gdb) si
Cannot access memory at address 0x4
(gdb) si
0x00000001 in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
Disabling display 1 to avoid infinite recursion.
0x1:    Cannot access memory at address 0x1
(gdb) q
```

---

For i386 at least, the ELF loader sets up a sensible stack before entering the loaded code, so you *can* set the ELF entry point to a C function and get reasonable behaviour; however, as I mentioned above, you have to handle a clean process exit yourself.  And if you're not using the C runtime, you'd better not be using any libraries that depend on the C runtime either.

So here is an example of that, using your original linker script - but with the C code modified to initialise `a` to a known value, and invoke an `exit` system call (using inline assembly) with the final value of `a` as the exit code.  (Note: I've just realised that you haven't said exactly what platform you're using; I'm assuming Linux here.)

```
$ cat main2.c
void mymain(void)
{
  int a = 42;
  a++;
  asm volatile("mov $1,%%eax; mov %0,%%ebx; int $0x80" : : "r"(a) : "%eax" );
}
$ gcc -c main2.c
$ ld -o prog2 -T my_script.lds main2.o
$ ./prog2 ; echo $?
43
$
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew for the anwser. I say that program crashes on startup because gdb says this...I know that before `main` other function are called, for example ctors i think. But if i would another name for `main` where should i specify that? And, if i link my program explicitly with `ld` must i pass also c runtime object files?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Are you wanting to use the normal C runtime and libraries?  If so, your main function must be called `main`: that's what the C runtime calls.  (That's not the same thing as the ELF entry point, which is normally `_start` in `crt1.o`.)
If you're invoking `ld` directly, then yes, you must link the various C runtime files yourself.  If you're using `gcc`, it will do that for you.  You can see what it does with `gcc -v`, but you need to know that it invokes `ld` via a wrapper, `collect2` (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gccint/Collect2.html)).

Comment: I would know if is possible build an executable (ELF format) that runs correctly without linking it to the c runtime objects files.

Comment: Yes, as long as you can live without the things that the C runtime code does for you.  I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Yes, i'm using Linux...I don't know why but if i reproduce your steps (compilation and linking and debugging with gdb) gdb says another thing: `During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.` so i can't not even start debugging. I'm using `gcc 4.4.5`.

Comment: Works for me on both an old Debian 5.0 system and a recent Fedora 15 system, so I'm afraid I don't know.  Maybe your system has something different about it (kernel configuration options? SELinux enabled? something else?) which means that it doesn't like the addresses you're linking at: Linux elf32-i386 binaries are usually linked to run at a much higher address, 0x08048000 (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2966426)).  But I can't reproduce your problem, so that's just a guess.

Comment: Ok. i'll investigate!Thank you very much Matthew.

Comment: @MirkoBanchi I also got the same issue. It seems the elf file is generated incorrectly. I fixed it using a small application (not sure if there is any easy way). More info on what i did [here](http://www.mesysdev.com/bare-assembly-x86-on-linux-part-2/)

Answer (score 2):

yes to run on linux, we need to change .lds file

```
SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x8048000;
   .text : { *(.text) 
}
```