# In an ELF file, how does the address for _start get detemined?

Tags: elf, symbols

I've been reading the ELF specification and cannot figure out where the program entry point and _start address come from.

It seems like they should have to be in a pretty consistent place, but I made a few trivial programs, and _start is always in a different place.

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_start` symbol may be defined in any object file. Normally it is generated automatically (it corresponds to `main` in C). You can generate it yourself, for instance in an assembler source file:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    // assembly here
```

When the linker has processed all object files it looks for the `_start` symbol and puts its value in the `e_entry` field of the [elf header](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/1998-04-29/ch4.eheader.html). The loader takes the address from this field and makes a call to it after it has finished loading all sections in memory and is ready to execute the file.

Comment: Well usually, `_start` is not really `main` at least with GCC/glibc: `_start` calls initialization functions, then `main`, then `exit()` with the value returned by `main`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the linker script `ld` is using:

```
ld -verbose
```

The format is documented at: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/Scripts.html

It determines basically everything about how the executable will be generated.

On Binutils 2.24 Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, it contains the line:

```
ENTRY(_start)
```

which sets the entry point to the `_start` symbol (goes to the ELF header as mentioned by ctn)

And then:

```
. = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
```

which sets the address of the first headers to `0x400000` + `SIZEOF_HEADERS`.

I have modified that address to `0x800000`, passed my custom script with `ld -T` and it worked: `readelf -s` says that `_start` is at that address.

Another way to change it is to use the `-Ttext-segment=0x800000` option.

The reason for using `0x400000` = 4Mb = `getconf PAGE_SIZE` is to start at the beginning of the second page as asked at: [Why is the ELF execution entry point virtual address of the form 0x80xxxxx and not zero 0x0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187484/why-is-the-elf-execution-entry-point-virtual-address-of-the-form-0x80xxxxx-and-n)

A question describes how to set `_start` from the command line: [Why is the ELF entry point 0x8048000 not changeable with the "ld -e" option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116648/why-is-the-elf-entry-point-0x8048000-not-changeable?lq=1)

`SIZEOF_HEADERS` is the size of the ELF + program headers, which are at the beginning of the ELF file. That data gets loaded into the very beginning of the virtual memory space by Linux (TODO why?) In a minimal Linux x86-64 hello world with 2 program headers it is worth `0xb0`, so that the `_start` symbol comes at 0x4000b0.

Comment: 4MiB is two x86-64 largepages.  Only legacy 32-bit (non-PAE) paging on x86 uses 4M largepages.  [Why is address 0x400000 chosen as a start of text segment in x86\_64 ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689516/why-is-address-0x400000-chosen-as-a-start-of-text-segment-in-x86-64-abi/67679629#67679629)  But the standard page size is 4k.

Comment: And BTW, modern distros configure GCC to use `ld -pie`, which selects a different linker script.  `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie` or just plain `ld` will still work this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this link http://www.docstoc.com/docs/23942105/UNIX-ELF-File-Format
at page 8 it is shown where the entry point is if it is executable. Basically you need to calculate the offset and you got it.
Make sure to remember the little endianness of x86 ( i guess you use it) and reorder if you read bytewise edit: or maybe not i'm not quit sure about this to be honest.