# Why is the ELF entry point 0x8048000 not changeable with the "ld -e" option?

Tags: linker, elf, memory-layout

Following up [Why is the ELF execution entry point virtual address of the form 0x80xxxxx and not zero 0x0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187484/elf-binary-entry-point) and [Why do virtual memory addresses for linux binaries start at 0x8048000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966426/why-do-virtual-memory-addresses-for-linux-binaries-start-at-0x8048000), why cannot I make `ld` use a different entry point than the default with `ld -e`?

If I do so, I either get a `segmentation fault` with return code 139, even for addresses close by the default entry point. Why?

**EDIT:**

I will make the question more specific:

```
        .text
        .globl _start    
_start:
        movl   $0x4,%eax        # eax = code for 'write' system call   
        movl   $1,%ebx          # ebx = file descriptor to standard output
        movl   $message,%ecx    # ecx = pointer to the message
        movl   $13,%edx         # edx = length of the message
        int    $0x80            # make the system call
        movl   $0x0,%ebx        # the status returned by 'exit'
        movl   $0x1,%eax        # eax = code for 'exit' system call
        int    $0x80            # make the system call
        .data
        .globl message
message:        
        .string "Hello world\n" # The message as data
```

If I compile this with `as program.s -o program.o` and then link it statically with `ld -N program.o -o program`, `readelf -l program` shows `0x0000000000400078` as the `VirtAddr` of the text segment and `0x400078` as entry point. When run, `Hello world" is printed.

However, when I try to link with `ld -N -e0x400082 -Ttext=0x400082 program.o -o program` (moving text segment and entry point by 4 bytes), the program will be `killed`. Inspecting it with `readelf -l` now shows two different headers of type `LOAD`, one at `0x0000000000400082` and one at `0x00000000004000b0`.

When I try `0x400086`, it all works, and there is only one `LOAD` section.

1. What's going on here?
2. Which memory addresses may I chose, which ones cannot I chose and why?

Thanks you.

Comment: I have also been able to modify the entry point with the linker script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30536800/895245

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> why cannot I make ld use a different entry point than the default with ld -e

You sure can. This:

```c
int foo(int argc, char *argv[]) { return 0; }
```

```bash
gcc main.c -Wl,-e,foo
```

wouldn't work, because the execution doesn't start at main. It starts at `_start`, which is linked from `crt0.o` (part of glibc) and arranges for things like dynamic linking, etc. to start up properly. By redirecting `_start` to `foo`, you've bypassed all that required glibc initialization, and so things don't work.

But if you don't need dynamic linking, and are willing to do what glibc normally does for you, then you can name the entry point whatever you want. Example:

```c
#include <syscall.h>

int foo()
{
  syscall(SYS_write, 1, "Hello, world\n", 13);
  syscall(SYS_exit, 0);
}
```

```bash
gcc t.c -static -nostartfiles -Wl,-e,foo && ./a.out
Hello, world
```

Oh, and your title of this question doesn't match your actual question (bad idea(TM)).

To answer the question in the title, you sure *can* change the address your executable is linked at. By default, you get `0x8048000` load address (only in 32-bits; 64-bit default is `0x400000`).

You can easily change that to e.g. `0x80000` by adding `-Wl,-Ttext-segment=0x80000` to the link line.

Update:

> However, when I try to link with ld -N -e0x400082 -Ttext=0x400082 program.o -o program (moving text segment and entry point by 4 bytes), the program will be killed.

Well, it is impossible to assign `Ttext` to `0x400082` without violating `.text` section alignment constraint (which is 4). You must keep the .text address aligned on at least 4-byte boundary (or change the required alignment of `.text`).

When I set the start address to 0x400078, 0x40007c, 0x400080, 0x400084, ..., 0x400098 and use GNU-ld 2.20.1, the program works.

However, when I use current CVS snapshot of binutils, the program works for 0x400078, 0x40007c, 0x400088, 0x40008c, and gets Killed for 0x400080, 0x400084, 0x400090, 0x400094, 0x400098. This might be a bug in the linker, or I am violating some other constraint (I don't see which though).

At this point, if you are *really* interested, I suggest downloading binutils sources, building `ld`, and figuring out what exactly causes it to create two `PT_LOAD` segments instead of one.

Update 2:

> Force new segment for sections with overlapping LMAs.

Ah! That just means you need to move `.data` out of the way. This makes a working executable:

```
ld -N -o t t.o -e0x400080 -Ttext=0x400080 -Tdata=0x400180
```

Comment: I updated my question to make a better example of what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, great answer, I did not consider the alignment.

Comment: I used git bisect to find then change between binutils 2.20 and 2.21 that introduces the change you describe. It's called "elf.c (_bfd_elf_map_sections_to_segments): Force new segment for sections with overlapping LMAs." (http://repo.or.cz/w/binutils.git/commit/278c98e2ff1c95c8ad9579755abda467ea2bc1b4)