# Declaring array in pthreads start_routine function causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, stack-overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* function(void* arg){
  int picture[4096][4096];
}

int main(){
  int N=10, S=10;
  pthread_t pids[10];
  pthread_create(&pids[0], NULL, function, NULL);
  pthread_join(pids[0], NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above code with: `gcc test.c -pthread`.

On running the executable, it crashes, displaying: `Segmentation fault`.

But, if I remove the `int picture[4096][4096];` definition, it doesn't crash.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crashing program is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *function(void *arg)
{
  int picture[4096][4096]; // 4096*4096*sizeof(int) = 67108864 bytes = 64 MB
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t pids[10];
  pthread_create(&pids[0],NULL, function, NULL);
  pthread_join(pids[0],NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

The program crashes at execution time:

```
$ gcc p.c -lpthread
$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

### Thread stack layout

The default stack size for a thread in the **GLIBC/pthread** is **8 MB**. At thread creation time, the Thread descriptor also called Task Control Block (TCB), is stored at the bottom of the stack and a red zone (guard page of 4 KB without read/write permission is set at the top of the stack). The stack grows from the high to low addresses.

Result of the program under the control of `strace`:

```
$ strace -f ./a.out
[...]
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fee8d4dc000
mprotect(0x7fee8d4dd000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x556cf1b72000
brk(0x556cf1b93000)                     = 0x556cf1b93000
clone(child_stack=0x7fee8dcdbfb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTIDstrace: Process 3338 attached
, parent_tid=[3338], tls=0x7fee8dcdc700, child_tidptr=0x7fee8dcdc9d0) = 3338
[pid  3338] set_robust_list(0x7fee8dcdc9e0, 24 <unfinished ...>
[pid  3337] futex(0x7fee8dcdc9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 3338, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  3338] <... set_robust_list resumed>) = 0
[pid  3338] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7fee8d4dcef0} ---
[pid  3337] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid  3338] +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

In the preceding:

- The pthread library grabs the default stack size with a call to *getrlimit()* which returns 8 MB:
  `prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0`
- The pthread library allocates the stack zone of 8MB + 4 KB of guard page with a call to *mmap()* with no read/write permissions (i.e. **PROT_NONE**):
  `mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fee8d4dc000`
- The pthreads library calls *mprotect()* to set the read/write (i.e. **PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE**) permission on the memory zone except the first 4 KB of guard page (will serve to detect the stack overflows)
  `mprotect(0x7fee8d4dd000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0`
- The thread is created with a call to *clone()* (the beginning of the stack is set at 0x7fee8dcdbfb0)
  `clone(child_stack=0x7fee8dcdbfb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[3338], tls=0x7fee8dcdc700, child_tidptr=0x7fee8dcdc9d0) = 3338`

Hence the following memory space layout:

```
              +      +--------------------+ 0x7fee8d4dc000
              |      |                    |
      4 KB    |      |      RED ZONE      |
   (PROT_NONE)|      |    (guard page)    |
              +      +--------------------+ 0x7fee8d4dd000
              |      |                    |
              |      |                    |
              |      |          ^         |
    8192 KB   |      |          |         |
(PROT_READ/WRITE)    |        Stack       |
              |      |          |         |
              |      |          |         |
              |      +--------------------+ 0x7fee8dcdbfb0
              |      |                    |
              |      |     TCB + TLS      |
              |      |                    |
              +      +--------------------+ 0x7fee8dcdd000
```

### Why your program crashed

The thread entry point defines a table of `4096x4096x4` bytes which is equal to 64 MB. This is **too much** for the 8 MB long stack area. However, **we could expect no crash at all as the function defines a huge local table but there is no read/write access into it. So, no crash should occur**.

The `strace` logs show that the crash occurs upon access to address *0x7fee8d4dcef0* which is above the stack area in the allocated memory zone:
`[pid  3338] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7fee8d4dcef0} ---`

It is actually **in the guard page**:

```
              +      +--------------------+ 0x7fee8d4dc000
              |      |                    |
      4 KB    |      |      RED ZONE <--------- Trap @ si_addr=0x7fee8d4dcef0
   (PROT_NONE)|      |                    |            si_code=SEGV_ACCERR
              +      +--------------------+ 0x7fee8d4dd000
              |      |                    |
              |      |                    |
              |      |          ^         |
    8192 KB   |      |          |         |
(PROT_READ/WRITE)    |        Stack       |
              |      |          |         |
              |      |          |         |
              |      +--------------------+ 0x7fee8dcdbfb0
              |      |                    |
              |      |     TCB + TLS      |
              |      |                    |
              +      +--------------------+ 0x7fee8dcdd000
```

The core dump analysis under `gdb` provides the following location for the crash:

```
$ gdb a.out core
[...]
(gdb) where
#0  0x00005594eb9461a0 in function (arg=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fe95459ded8>) at p.c:56
#1  0x00007fe95879d609 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:477
#2  0x00007fe9586c4293 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
(gdb) disas /m
Dump of assembler code for function function:
56  void* function(void* arg){
   0x00005594eb946189 <+0>: endbr64 
   0x00005594eb94618d <+4>: push   %rbp
   0x00005594eb94618e <+5>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00005594eb946191 <+8>: lea    -0x4000000(%rsp),%r11
   0x00005594eb946199 <+16>:    sub    $0x1000,%rsp
=> 0x00005594eb9461a0 <+23>:    orq    $0x0,(%rsp)
   0x00005594eb9461a5 <+28>:    cmp    %r11,%rsp
   0x00005594eb9461a8 <+31>:    jne    0x5594eb946199 <function+16>
   0x00005594eb9461aa <+33>:    sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x00005594eb9461ae <+37>:    mov    %rdi,-0x4000018(%rbp)
   0x00005594eb9461b5 <+44>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00005594eb9461be <+53>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00005594eb9461c2 <+57>:    xor    %eax,%eax

57    int picture[4096][4096];
58  }
```

The above disassembly code of the thread entry point shows that `gcc` generates stack accesses every 4 KB (memory page size). It first sets `R11` register with the address of the beginning of the local table (*0x4000000* is *4096x4096xsizeof(int) = 67108864 bytes*):

```
   0x00005594eb946191 <+8>: lea    -0x4000000(%rsp),%r11
```

Then, it loops "oring" the content of the stack with 0 every 4096 bytes (0x1000):

```
   0x00005594eb946199 <+16>:    sub    $0x1000,%rsp
=> 0x00005594eb9461a0 <+23>:    orq    $0x0,(%rsp)
   0x00005594eb9461a5 <+28>:    cmp    %r11,%rsp
   0x00005594eb9461a8 <+31>:    jne    0x5594eb946199 <function+16>
```

**Hence, the crash because at some point, the `orq` instruction occurs in the guard page of the stack!**

**N.B.**:

- The reason for the "apparently useless" generated code is the protection against the *Stack Clash class of vulnerabilities* as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63402704/14393739)
- Of course, compiling the same code **with an optimization option would not trigger any crash** as *function()* would not contain any code:

```
$ gcc p.c -lpthread -O2
$ ./a.out
```

The optimized disassembly code of *function()* is a simple "return":

```
$ objdump -S a.out
[...]
00000000000011f0 <function>:
    11f0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    11f4:   c3                      retq   
    11f5:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    11fc:   00 00 00 
    11ff:   90                      nop
```

### How to set a bigger stack for the thread

As seen above, by default, the **GLIBC/pthread** library allocates a default stack of 8 MB. But it also provides the ability to set a stack allocated by the user or simply define the stack size with the following steps:

- Define thread attributes with *[pthread_attr_init()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html)*;
- Set the stack size in the attributes with *[pthread_attr_setstacksize()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html)*;
- Pass the attributes as second parameter to *[pthread_create()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)*;
- Call *[pthread_attr_destroy()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_destroy.3p.html)* to free the attributes.

Here is an enhanced version of the program which defines a stack of 65 MB for the thread:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* function(void* arg)
{
  int picture[4096][4096];    // 4096*4096*sizeof(int) = 67108864 bytes = 64 MB
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t pids[10];
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, 65*1024*1024);
  pthread_create(&pids[0], &attr, function, NULL);
  pthread_join(pids[0], NULL);
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  return 0;
}
```

Build and execution:

```
$ gcc p2.c -lpthread
$ ./a.out
```

There is no crash. With `strace`, we can verify the behavior:

```
$ strace ./a.out
[...]
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 68161536, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fe55afd3000
mprotect(0x7fe55afd4000, 68157440, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55b9d7ade000
brk(0x55b9d7aff000)                     = 0x55b9d7aff000
clone(child_stack=0x7fe55f0d2fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[5199], tls=0x7fe55f0d3700, child_tidptr=0x7fe55f0d39d0) = 5199
futex(0x7fe55f0d39d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 5199, NULL) = 0
munmap(0x7fe55afd3000, 68161536)        = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

We can see in the above traces:

- A call to *mmap()* of *65 MB + 4KB = 66564 KB = 68161536 bytes* (i.e. *65 MB + 4 KB* of guard page rounded up to the greater 4 KB page boundary)
  `mmap(NULL, 68161536, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fe55afd3000`
- A call to *mprotect()* on the first 68157440 bytes to set the guard page in the remaining 4KB
  `mprotect(0x7fe55afd4000, 68157440, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0`

Hence the new memory space layout:

```
              +      +--------------------+ 0x7fe55afd3000
              |      |                    |
      4 KB    |      |      RED ZONE      |
   (PROT_NONE)|      |                    |              
              +      +--------------------+ 0x7fe55afd4000
              |      |                    |
              |      |                    |
              |      |          ^         |
   66560 KB   |      |          |         |
(PROT_READ/WRITE)    |        Stack       |
              |      |          |         |
              |      |          |         |
              |      +--------------------+ 0x7fe55f0d2fb0
              |      |                    |
              |      |     TCB + TLS      |
              |      |                    |
              +      +--------------------+ 0x7FE55F0D4000
```

### Conclusion

From a simple program ending into a strange crash, we took the opportunity to study the thread's stack layout in the **GLIBC/pthread** library as well as the protection mechanism against the stack overflows and the stack size configuration.
However, **from a program design point of view**, we should never allocate so huge variables in the stack. In the current program, the table should be dynamically allocated or defined as a global variable (in Thread Local Storage) for examples. But it is another story...

Answer (score 1):

I generated core dump file. I ran the core dump file. It gave me the following:

```
#0  0x00005643352ba745 in function (arg=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fe80b054ed8>) at Pthred_kk.c:5
        picture = <error reading variable picture (value requires 67108864 bytes, which is more than max-value-size)>
#1  0x00007fe80f6526db in start_thread (arg=0x7fe80f055700) at pthread_create.c:463
        pd = 0x7fe80f055700
        now = <optimized out>
        unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {140634661148416, 8554578219241222147, 140634661146560, 0, 0, 140724934020640, 
                -8545604918547140605, -8545605192128745469}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, priv = {pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, data = {prev = 0x0, 
              cleanup = 0x0, canceltype = 0}}}
        not_first_call = <optimized out>
#2  0x00007fe80f37b88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

> picture = <error reading variable picture (value requires 67108864
> bytes, which is more than max-value-size)

In linux, the maxmum stack size for a thread is about 8MB.
As you can see the size (67108864 bytes) of `picture` is more than the maximum size (8MB = 8 * 1024 *1024 = 8388608).

Comment: Thanks That was really cool. On a side note. How did you take the core dump to see that error ? And is there a way to increase the stack size of thread ?

Comment: @Amitwadhwa  See this link to know about generation of core dump https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/28/debugging-a-segfault-on-linux/

Comment: Although it is not directly relevant to this. But just asking in case you have a quick answer.
I followed the steps in the blog but couldn't see the line that you pasted. Also, I am not sure how to execute this `symbol-file /path/to/my/binary
sharedlibrary`

Comment: 1) ulimit -c unlimited    2)  sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core_%e_%p  3) gdb <executable-file>  <core dump file>

Comment: After  step 2), core dump file will be stored in /tmp folder. You can change the path as you wish.

Comment: I did that but could not see the line `picture = <error reading variable picture (value` in it. Although the stuff is quite similar