# why my x64 process base address not start from 0x400000?

Tags: c, linux, bash, linker, 64-bit

I learned from this link [Why is address 0x400000 chosen as a start of text segment in x86_64 ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689516/why-is-address-0x400000-chosen-as-a-start-of-text-segment-in-x86-64-abi) that 64-bit Linux process start address by default should be 0x400000, but on my Ubuntu, I only found my `bash` process starts from a very high base address (0x55971cea6000).
Any one knows why? and how does dynamic linker choose the start address for a 64-bit process?

```
$ uname -r
5.15.0-25-generic

$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
...

$ file /usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=33a5554034feb2af38e8c75872058883b2988bc5, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ ld -verbose | grep -i text-segment
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;

$ cat maps
55971ce77000-55971cea6000 r--p 00000000 08:02 153 /usr/bin/bash
55971cea6000-55971cf85000 r-xp 0002f000 08:02 153 /usr/bin/bash
55971cf85000-55971cfbf000 r--p 0010e000 08:02 153 /usr/bin/bash
55971cfc0000-55971cfc4000 r--p 00148000 08:02 153 /usr/bin/bash
55971cfc4000-55971cfcd000 rw-p 0014c000 08:02 153 /usr/bin/bash
55971cfcd000-55971cfd8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
...

$ readelf -h /usr/bin/bash
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Position-Independent Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x32eb0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          1394600 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         13
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         30
  Section header string table index: 29
```

Comment: x64 is a Windows architecture (Software that runs on AMD64 / x86-64 ), there is no x64 in the Linux world.

Comment: /proc/pid/maps file. Replace pid with the pid number of bash process

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is the virtual memory after `0x400000` is moved by ASLR. Do you understand ASLR?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 what??! Linux certainly runs on this CPU architecture.

Comment: @user253751 Their note isn't on what it supports, it's on the fact that "x64" is a marketing name that seems to have been mostly used by software vendors, especially Microsoft, but is often not considered to be the "proper" name. They're a bit aggressive in denouncing it, because x64 is used by a lot of third parties to refer to the architecture, but I personally see that as sloppy when used in educational materials.

Comment: @user253751 There is no CPU architecture called x64. x64 is a architecture + calling convention used by Microsoft software for the AMD64 architecture / x86-64 architecture. There are some differences to the standard AMD64, for example x64 has no red zone and uses different registers for arguments.

Comment: So how would you refer to 64bits archs?

Comment: It's the same architecture, no matter what you call it!

Comment: @user253751 No. The CPU architecture is called AMD64, x86-64 or Intel64. x64 is about software. AMD64 software has a red zone, x64 does not have one. Similar to how x32 software uses the AMD64 architecture but the software is different than the standard AMD64 software.

Comment: For anyone not familiar with ASLR like me: Address space layout randomization (ASLR) is a memory-protection process for operating systems (OSes) that guards against buffer-overflow attacks by randomizing the location where system executables are loaded into memory.

Comment: @Fra93: x86-64 or AMD64.  Or if you're talking to Windows people, x64 is a short-hand option (and widely understood by others, despite most people knowing it's not the real name of the ISA in any vendor manuals.)  See [The most correct way to refer to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of programs for x86-related CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53364320)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I learned from this link Why is address 0x400000 chosen as a start of text segment in x86_64

That address is used for executables (`ELF` type `ET_EXEC`).

> I only found my bash process starts from a very high base address (0x55971cea6000). Any one knows why?

Because your `bash` is (newer) position-independent executable (`ELF` type `ET_DYN`). It behaves much like a shared library, and is relocated to random address at runtime.

The `0x55971cea6000` address you found will vary from one execution to another. In contrast, `ET_EXEC` executables can only run correctly when loaded at their "linked at" address (typically `0x400000`).

> how does dynamic linker choose the start address for a 64-bit process?

The dynamic linker doesn't choose the start address of the executable -- the kernel does (by the time the dynamic linker starts running, the executable has already been `mmap`ed into memory).

The kernel looks at the `.e_type` in the `ELF` header and `.p_vaddr` field of the first program header and goes from there. IFF `.e_type == ET_EXEC`, then the kernel maps executable segments at their `.p_vaddr` addresses. For `ET_DYN`, if ASLR is in effect, the kernel performs `mmap`s at a random address.

Comment: Thanks @Employed Russian for the excellent explanation for my questions.

Comment: Address space layout randomization (ASLR) is a memory-protection process for operating systems (OSes) that guards against buffer-overflow attacks by randomizing the location where system executables are loaded into memory.