# Does the assembler choose where a program object file is stored in memory?

Tags: assembly, linker, loader

My textbook (*Computer Organization* by Hamacher et al.) says the following:

> The loader transfers the object program from the disk into a specified place in the memory. It must know the length of the program and the address in the memory where it will be loaded. The assembler usually places this information in a header in the object file, preceding the machine instructions and data of the object program.

It adds on and somewhat reiterates later with this:

> Once the object program has been loaded into the memory, the loader starts its execution by branching to the first instruction to be executed. In the source program, the programmer indicates the first instruction with a special address label such as START. The assembler includes the value of this address label in the header of the object program.

Now my question is the following: if the above is correct, how does the assembler know what address/value to assign to the label START? I am very much a novice when it comes to ideas about virtualization and the OS but I imagine it goes something like the assembler asking the OS where in the address space there might be enough space for the program's object file?

Comment: The assembler itself doesn't know, if it's just an assembler that makes a relocatable `.o` object file, not a final executable (which FASM can do).  The linker chooses, for traditional Linux executables for example.  (For modern position-independent executables, the address is randomized by the kernel; the linker just lays things out relative to a base address.)

Comment: Semi-related: [Why Linux/gnu linker chose address 0x400000?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14314021) mentions that the default linker script for `ld` contains that address, but the answer is mostly about why that's a good choice on x86-64.   [Why is address 0x400000 chosen as a start of text segment in x86\_64 ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67679629) mentions that the ABI doc even specifies that address.

Comment: Does that mean my book is wrong in its description of the assembler putting the START address in the header of the object file or is that reconcilable somehow? @PeterCordes

Comment: Yeah, their terminology doesn't match normal usage for systems like Linux.  An object file normally means a `.o` or `.obj` like you get from `gcc -c foo.c` or `gcc -c foo.S`, which is relocatable and still needs to be linked before it can be executed.  Linking with a program like GNU Binutils `ld` turns one or more `.o` files into an executable.

Comment: Everything they're saying is true for **executables** produced by assembling + linking, though.  Or for executables produced directly by an assembler like FASM, which has a mode to output an ELF or Windows executable instead of a `.o` or `.obj`.

Comment: Just because I'm very much a rookie, I want to confirm: you're saying their description is appropriate in the special case of a source program which, when assembled, is executable (no linking needed) or, more generally, for any source program once the assembly+linking process is done (and in this latter case it's the linker, which knows how many lines will be in the final executable, which puts a START address in the executable header? @PeterCordes

Comment: Let's talk about Linux ELF executables for example.  The ELF header *for a linked executable or shared object (PIE executable or library)* includes an "entry point" field which the kernel's program-loader uses to set the initial program-counter after loading.  The linker looks for a `_start` symbol so it can put its address in that field.  At least one assembler is capable of producing an ELF executable directly from asm source, if it includes a directive telling FASM to do that instead of make a `.o`.  But you could just as well describe this as the assembler having a linker built-in.

Comment: (If the asm source includes the `db` and `dd` directives to emit data for the fields of the ELF header instead of leaving that to a linker, then other assemblers in flat-binary mode will end up making an executable.  e.g. https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html shows an example of making minimal-sized executables by doing this to avoid any extra bytes normal tools include in executables.)

Comment: *which knows how many lines will be in the final executable* - uhhh, no.  A linker only knows the total size in bytes of the sections in the `.o` files it's linking, symbol addresses relative to the start of a section in each file, and relocation entries where it has to fill in the final address (absolute or relative) for symbols.  It doesn't know how many asm source lines produced those bytes of machine code.  And it doesn't matter for setting the entry-point address to the address where `START` (or `_start`) ended up in the linked executable.