# Is the pointer guaranteed to be > a certain value?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, new-operator, ram

In C++ when i do `new` (or even malloc) is there any guarantee that the return address will be greater than a certain value? Because... in this project i find it -very- useful to use 0-1k as a enum. But i wouldn't want to do that if its possible to get a value that low. My only target systems are 32 or 64bit CPUs with the OS window/linux and mac.

Does the standard say anything about pointers? Does windows or linux say anything about their C runtime and what the lowest memory address (for ram) is?

-edit- i end up modifying my `new` overload to check if the address is above >1k. I call std::terminate if it doesn't.

Comment: Why are you using enums as pointers?

Comment: @Pubby: It’s common (particularly in interpreters and games) to rely on platform-specific pointer characteristics to stuff extra information into them, usually to eliminate indirection. Because of alignment rules, the bottom three bits are free; in addition, 64-bit systems generally have userspace pointers with only 48 significant bits; the rest are all `1` or `0`, so you can pack a pointer into the (53-bit) mantissa of a `double` with its upper bits set to represent `NaN`. Then the low-order flags let you quickly choose between representations with masking and shifting.

Comment: It appears i only need 6 bits so i won't even need the first 1 or 4k :).

Comment: You might want to check out [how Ruby stores values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75633126/how-is-value-in-ruby-sometimes-a-pointer-and-sometimes-not). They apparently assume that the first 3 bits are never set in a pointer. And that's just the beginning of the story. Supposedly this has something to do with alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such guarantee. You can try using [placement `new`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) if you need very specific memory locations but it has certain problems that you'll have to [work hard to avoid](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/heap.html). Why don't you try using a map with an integer key that has the pointer as its value instead? That way you wouldn't have to rely on specific memory addresses and ranges.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of standard, there is nothing. But in reality, it depends on the target OS, windows for instance reserves the first 64kb of memory as a no-mans land (depending on the build it is read-only memory, else it is marked as PAGE_NOACCESS), while it uses the upper 0x80000000+ for kernel memory, but it can be changed, see [this](http://www.openrce.org/reference_library/files/reference/Windows%20Memory%20Layout,%20User-Kernel%20Address%20Spaces.pdf) & [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

On x64 you can also use the higher bits of the address (only 47bits are used for addresses currently), but its not such a good idea, as later on it will change and your program will break (AMD who set the standard also advise against it).

Answer (score 2):

In theory, no -- a pointer's not even guaranteed to be > 0.  However, in practice, viewed as an unsigned integer (don't forget that a pointer may have a high-order "1" bit), no system that I know of would have a pointer value less than about 1000.  But relying on that is relying on "undefined behavior".

Comment: reference? I think I recall reading that the first 1GB in linux virtual memory is only for the kernel, [so if it is true, your application will not get an address in the first 1GB, unless it runs on kernel mode] However, I might be wrong about the initial assumption, I cannot remember where I think I read it :\

Comment: @amit my google-fu came up with this http://linux-mm.org/HighMemory "3GB for user programs and 1GB for the kernel"

Comment: @amit -- I was speaking very generally -- C++ runs on some pretty small systems.

Comment: On Linux, the kernel-user space division is configurable in the kernel, so at least the 3 splits: 1-3 GB, 2-2 GB and 3-1 GB are common on 32-bit systems. This links is somewhat old but quite detailed: http://kerneltrap.org/node/2450

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for where valid memory addresses come from; to write safe system-independent code, you cannot rely on certain addresses (and even with anecdotal support, you never know when that will change with a new system update).

Answer (score 1):

It's very platform-specific, so I would discourage relying on this kind of information unless you have a very good reason and are aware of consequences for portability, maintainability etc.

NULL is guaranteed to be 0x0 always. If I recall correctly, x86 reserves the first 128 MB of address space as "NULL-equivalent", so that valid pointers can't take on values in this range. On x64 there are some [additional addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X64#Canonical_form_addresses) which you shouldn't encounter in practice, at least for now.

As for address space reserved for the operating system, it will clearly depend on the OS. On Linux, the kernel-user space division is configurable in the kernel, so at least the 3 splits: 1-3 GB, 2-2 GB and 3-1 GB are common on 32-bit systems. You can find more details [on kerneltrap](http://kerneltrap.org/node/2450).

Comment: Surely you meant the first 128 *K* B of address space?

Comment: @CodyGray No, it's actually 128 MB, not kB. But I was not quite right about the causes. It's not caused by the CPU itself but rather by the layout of applications' address space on most UNIX-like systems. The area 0-128 MB is reserved for the stack, meaning you don't get addresses from this range when using `new` or `malloc()` which allocate memory from the heap. It's explained very well in [this nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2187753/1224016).