# How is VALUE in Ruby sometimes a pointer, and sometimes not?

Tags: c, ruby

I mean they basically assume that there can't be a pointer with any of the first 3 bits (or more) set.

Here's a [function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/value_type.h#L223-L251) that determines the type of a value:

```
static inline enum ruby_value_type
rb_type(VALUE obj)
{
    if (! RB_SPECIAL_CONST_P(obj)) {
        return RB_BUILTIN_TYPE(obj);
    }
    else if (obj == RUBY_Qfalse) {
        return RUBY_T_FALSE;
    }
    else if (obj == RUBY_Qnil) {
        return RUBY_T_NIL;
    }
    else if (obj == RUBY_Qtrue) {
        return RUBY_T_TRUE;
    }
    else if (obj == RUBY_Qundef) {
        return RUBY_T_UNDEF;
    }
    ...
```

`RUBY_Q*` are [constants](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/special_consts.h#L98-L106):

```
    RUBY_Qfalse         = 0x00, /* ...0000 0000 */
    RUBY_Qnil           = 0x04, /* ...0000 0100 */
    RUBY_Qtrue          = 0x14, /* ...0001 0100 */
    RUBY_Qundef         = 0x24, /* ...0010 0100 */
    RUBY_IMMEDIATE_MASK = 0x07, /* ...0000 0111 */
    RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG    = 0x01, /* ...xxxx xxx1 */
    RUBY_FLONUM_MASK    = 0x03, /* ...0000 0011 */
    RUBY_FLONUM_FLAG    = 0x02, /* ...xxxx xx10 */
    RUBY_SYMBOL_FLAG    = 0x0c, /* ...xxxx 1100 */
    ...
    RUBY_SPECIAL_SHIFT  = 8 /**< Least significant 8 bits are reserved. */
```

[`RB_SPECIAL_CONST_P()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/special_consts.h#L326-L330):

```
static inline bool
RB_SPECIAL_CONST_P(VALUE obj)
{
    return RB_IMMEDIATE_P(obj) || obj == RUBY_Qfalse;
}
```

[`RB_IMMEDIATE_P()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/special_consts.h#L310-L314):

```
static inline bool
RB_IMMEDIATE_P(VALUE obj)
{
    return obj & RUBY_IMMEDIATE_MASK;
}
```

[`RB_BUILTIN_TYPE`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/value_type.h#L180-L192):

```
static inline enum ruby_value_type
RB_BUILTIN_TYPE(VALUE obj)
{
    ...
    VALUE ret = RBASIC(obj)->flags & RUBY_T_MASK;
    return RBIMPL_CAST((enum ruby_value_type)ret);
}
```

[`RBASIC`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/core/rbasic.h#L40):

```
#define RBASIC(obj)                 RBIMPL_CAST((struct RBasic *)(obj))
```

So, unless the first 3 bits are set, they use `VALUE` as a pointer. What makes them sure they won't one day receive a pointer with any of those bits set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All pointers to objects from ruby will come from `malloc` et. al.

From the man page for `malloc`:

> The  `malloc()`  and `calloc()` functions return a pointer to the allocated
> memory, which is suitably aligned for any  built-in  type.

Thus, `malloc` *must* allow (e.g.):

```
double *dptr = malloc(sizeof(*dptr));
```

The alignment for `double` is 8 bytes.

This is true for *all* [all POSIX compliant] systems.
Actually, it's usually the CPU architecture that dictates the alignment.

- Some systems *require* such alignment (or an access will cause the H/W to generate an alignment exception).
- Even if the H/W will tolerate a non-aligned fetch/store, the S/W will generate the natural alignment anyway [sometimes for performance reasons--the aligned access can be faster].

So, at a minimum, the least significant bits 3 bits of a pointer *must* be 0.

For some arches, the compiler supports (e.g.) `__int128`, so the required alignment would be 16.

Also, some systems (e.g. `x86`) also support SIMD types which are 16 bytes. So, again, an alignment of 16 bytes.

For 16 byte alignment, the least significant 4 bits would be 0.

Although you only *rely* on 8 byte alignment [and LSB of 3 being 0], frequently [but *not* always] that the least significant 4 bits are 0.

So, *always*, you *can* rely on the least significant 3 bits being 0.

Comment: It seems like alignment is implementation-dependent. [From C11](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (page 48): `An alignment is an
implementation-defined integer value representing...`. Also there are [typical alignments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86) in Wikipedia.

Comment: While alignment is implementation-defined, YARV is only supported on specific versions of specific implementations running on specific versions of specific Operating Systems on specific ISAs, so they know that all the possible implementations that are supported by YARV have the required alignment.