# Null pointer dereference in User space and kernel space

Tags: linux, kernel, userspace

what will happen if we dereference the null pointer in user space and kernel space?

From my understanding the behaviour is based on compiler,architecture,etc.

but in general for every user space program allocated with virtual memory and the paging is used to translate the virtual address to physical address using page tables.

so if we are dereferencing null pointer in user space,that address is invalid so the context switch will happen and in kernel based on the interrupt for this null pointer dereference 'Segmentation fault will come or page fault error will come'.

In Kernel space:

If we dereference the NULL pointer there is a possibility of crashing the system or kernel may not able to return from that call.

Is my understanding correct?or any other informations missing means please explain.

Ref:I have understood from this "[What happens in OS when we dereference a NULL pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645647/what-happens-in-os-when-we-dereference-a-null-pointer-in-c)"

Answer (score 3):

The kernel maps the page at virtual address 0 into all processes with no permission bits set. When you try to access that page, you get a [page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault). The kernel routine that handles it issues a `SIGSEGV` [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) to your process. If you have no handler for `SIGSEGV` registered, core is [dumped](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) and you see your "Segmentation fault" message.

Kernel side, things are a bit different. After all, the kernel is supposed to be robust:

- If the dereference happens and recovery is possible (e.g. your trackpad driver did the offence), a [kernel oops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_oops) is generated. The kernel continues running (for now).
- If the dereference occurs so that no recovery is possible, the Oops leads to a [kernel panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic). Reboot necessary.
- If for some reason, there is data mapped at page zero, you will corrupt memory. Which could lead to a panic down the way, go unnoticed or even be [abused for a privilege escalation attack](https://lwn.net/Articles/342330/).

Comment: :Thanks,one more doubt ,if we dereference null pointer in user space also it will call internally system calls right?,so what will make differ user space and kernel space?,is memory handling is different for both?i heard that userspace having less memory access as compared to kernel space.can you pls explain little bit about this?."The kernel maps the page at virtual address 0 into all processes with no permission bits set."can you please explain this?

Comment: You should check out the wikipedia article on virtual memory. It's too much to cover in a comment. In short, the memory management unit handles your pointer dereferences. When you dereference 0, the MMU sees it's not there and invokes the kernel. If the address is valid, the kernel is not involved.

Comment: It should be noted that what some refer to as a null pointer deref in user-space can also be abused. Consider `char x[42]; overflow_array(x, 42);` vs `char x[42]; overflow_array(42, x);` where `overflow_array` triggers some buffer overflow condition... They should both boil down to: let *a* be the expression `x[42+y] = something_else;` and *b* be the expression `42[x+y] = something_else;` where *a* expands to `*(x + 42 + y)` and *b* expands to `*(42 + x + y)`; it should be trivial to see how those two expressions are equivalent... Now consider `null_pointer[x+y]` vs `x[null_pointer+y]`...

Comment: What is that case in Linux or Windows when something is mapped to page zero?

Comment: @Gábor Emulation mostly. See https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/address_zero.html