# why linux process virtual space usually starts at 0x08048000?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

example：

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)

Entry point 0x80c7100

There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:

  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align

  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x00100 0x00100 R E 0x4

      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]

  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x3694c2 0x3694c2 R E 0x1000

.......
```

Comment: There are a number of web sites that show the memory layout of Linux processes, google them.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187484/elf-binary-entry-point