# Can the ELF entry point be different from the usual 0x80****** ? Why would that be done?

Tags: memory, elf

I'm playing around with a binary and when I load it into my debugger, or even run readelf, I noticed the entry point is 0x530 instead of the usual 0x80****** that'd learned ELF's were loaded at.

Why is this? Is there anything else going on? The binary is linked and not stripped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> instead of the usual `0x80******` that'd learned ELF's were loaded at.

You learned wrong.

While `0x804800` is the usual address that 32-bit x86 Linux binaries are linked at, that address is *by no means* universal or special.

64-bit `x86_64` and `aarch64` binaries are linked at default address of `0x40000`, and `powerpc64le` binaries at default address of `0x10000000`.

There is no reason a binary could not be linked at any other (page-aligned) address (so long as it is not `0`, and allows for sufficient stack at the high end of the address space.

> Why is this?

The binary was likely linked with a custom linker script. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Employed, the entry address is not fixed.

Just to verify, I've tried on x86_64:

```
gcc -Wl,-Ttext-segment=0x800000 hello_world.c
```

which sets the entry point to `0x800000` (+ the ELF header size, which gets loaded at `0x800000` in memory) instead of the default `0x400000`.

Then both:

```
readelf -h a.out
```

and `gdb -ex 'b _start'` tell me the entry is at `0x800440` as expected (the header is `0x440` bytes).

This is because that value is an input that tells the Linux kernel where to set the PC when forking a new process.

The default `0x400000` comes from the default linker script used. You can also modify the linker script as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31380105/895245 , change 0x400000 there, and use the new script with `-T script`

If I put it at anything below 0x200000 (2Mb) exactly or other low addresses, the program gets killed. I think this is because ld always loads the sections at multiples of 2Mb, which is the largest page size supported (in huge page), so anything lower starts at `0`, which is bad: [Why is the ELF execution entry point virtual address of the form 0x80xxxxx and not zero 0x0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187484/why-is-the-elf-execution-entry-point-virtual-address-of-the-form-0x80xxxxx-and-n)