# ELF file entry point is outside of the file?

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, ld, elf

I've been playing around with object files and ELF files, and I compiled a very basic assembly program using gcc like so:

`gcc -nostartfiles -static -nostdlib -fno-stack-protector -c test.s`

And then linking with `ld -o test test.o`. I was under the impression that this wouldn't link any C libraries or other code, and would purely assemble and build an executable from `test.s`. When I run `readelf -h test`, I get this output:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x401000
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4416 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         4
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         6
  Section header string table index: 5
```

which states that the entry point is address 0x401000. However, inspecting the output with hexdump, I noticed that my executable doesn't have an address 0x401000, and in fact ends at byte 0x0012C0. Where does the entry point address refer to?

Here is test.s:

```
    .global _start

    .text
_start:
        mov     $1, %rax                # system call 1 is write
        mov     $1, %rdi                # file handle 1 is stdout
        mov     $message, %rsi          # address of string to output
        mov     $13, %rdx               # number of bytes
        syscall                         # invoke operating system to do the write

        mov     $60, %rax               # system call 60 is exit
        xor     %rdi, %rdi              # we want return code 0
        syscall                         # invoke operating system to exit

message:
        .ascii  "Hello, world\n"
```

Comment: `0x401000` is a virtual address not a file offset. Consult program headers to map it to an offset.

Comment: @Jester ah ok thank you

Comment: Related: [Why is the ELF execution entry point virtual address of the form 0x80xxxxx and not zero 0x0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2187484) - `ld` for i386 chose an even higher default.